# Agora live streaming video are not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, live-streaming, agora.io

I'm making live streaming app with unity following. [this guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/interactive-live-streaming/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=unity). When testing with simulator, it has both video and audio but it  only has audio when I'm running the app on oculus quest 2.
I'm not sure if it is the same problem as **black screen** which is mentioned in the document or not.